# Ergodicity on the Profinite Integers versus Ergodicity on the $p$-adic integers

Tags: p-adic-number-theory, ergodic-theory, profinite-groups

Let $\mathbb{P}$ denote the set of prime numbers, let $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ denote the ring of $p$-adic integers, and let: $$\widetilde{\mathbb{Z}}\overset{\textrm{def}}{=}\prod_{p\in\mathbb{P}}\mathbb{Z}_{p}$$denote the ring of profinite integers. Using the haar probability measures on the $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$s, one can define a haar probability measure on $\widetilde{\mathbb{Z}}$ via the product measure construction. Now, let $q$ be an integer $\geq2$, and define:$$\widetilde{\mathbb{Z}}_{\textrm{off }q}\overset{\textrm{def}}{=}\prod_{\begin{array}{c}
p\in\mathbb{P}\\
p\nmid q
\end{array}}\mathbb{Z}_{p}$$ Next, letting $b\in\mathbb{Z}$, consider the formula $f\left(x\right)=qx+b$. I can show that $f$ then defines an ergodic map on $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ for all $p\nmid q$. My intuition tells me that this should then force $f$ to be an ergodic map on $\widetilde{\mathbb{Z}}_{\textrm{off }q}$, but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: If $p \nmid q,f(x)=qx+b$ then $f(a+p^k Z_p) = aq+b+q p^k Z_p=aq+b+p^k Z_p$ so $f(a+p^k Z_p)=a+p^k Z_p$ whenever $b=a(1-q) \bmod p^k$, it works the same way in $\prod_{p \ \nmid \ q} Z_p$

Comment: @MCS are you sure $f$ is always ergodic. Consider $f(x) = 2x$ and $p = 7$. Then the orbit of $(1,1,1,1,1,\dots)$ does not intersect $U_1(3)$, [see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number#Topology), since $2^n$ is never $3$ mod $7$.

Comment: @reuns: You're absolutely right! I was misreading my source material; my map is merely *measure-preserving*, not ergodic.